# md-sidenav responsive, with Flex-Layout

Tags: angular, responsive, angular-flex-layout

I make a app with Angular and Flex-Layout, I use breakpoints for hide the navbar. I need use the click event for show the navbar when this is hidden.
My code is followed:

```
<md-sidenav-container>
<md-toolbar>
    <button class="button" md-icon-button fxHide.gt-sm="true" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
      <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
    </button>
    <span class="title">Assistant</span>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true" fxHide fxShow.gt-sm>Drawer content</md-sidenav>
  <div class="my-content">Main content</div>
</md-sidenav-container>
```

The breakpoints work correctly, but the event click for toggle the navbar not work. Whats is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the `<md-sidenav>` with

```
<md-sidenav ... [fxHide]="hideSidebar" ...>Drawer content</md-sidenav>
```

and on your component create a global `hideSidebar` variable that keeps track of the state of the sidenav, so by clicking the button you'll set that variable to `true/false` and will show/hide the sidenav accordingly.

```
<button class="button" ... (click)="toggleSidebar()">

toggleSidebar(): void { this.hideSidebar = !this.hideSidebar }
```

Hope this helps and let me know if I misunderstood your question